# How to configure the physical machine and virtual machine?

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, tcp, tcpip

If I want to transfer data between the physical machine (windows operating system) and virtual machine (Linux real time operating system). Could anyone please explain about configuring the data between the machines.

Is it possible to configure the physical machine, and also how?

I am using Lab car VMware player on virtual machine.

Comment: What kind of data? if your mean is transferring Files between both of them, you can use Shared Folder feature.

Comment: I am transferring the data like temperature value, speed and so on. I also created a Ethernet driver (TCP/IP) for the communication

Answer (score 0):

The virtual machines are on a  virtual network, which  exists only in  the vmware. On the  vmware host (vmware player) you  can set  up

1)  the parameters of the internal network
2) how do you want to connect it to  the outer  world (with its  real network)

In your  case, 1) is important.

On the internal vmnet, your host and  your  guests have their ip-s just so,  as if it were a normal net.

If you have  correctly set up, you  can handle your  guests anyway  as you wish (IMHO  the    simplest if you  share some folder on  the  guest, and  copy   files  with  the normal  windows smb networking).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am using ip address to communicate with the physical machine. To perform the communication the address (IP or subnet) of the physical machine should be the same. How to configure or setup the physical or virtual machine of the same subnet ??

Comment: Simplest is if you  set the network of  your virtual machine in  bridged mode. It will be thus a neightbor machine on your local physical network, and you will be able to use of your local network settings (thus the local  dhcp will configure  everything to you).

Comment: I did as you said but its not working !!!

Comment: @user2984410 If your vms are in bridged mode, they should seem as if they were independent machines on your local network.

Comment: I selected a host on my vm : I am using windows operating system as a host and linux as VM on the same laptop. If I ping from the host or the target : I am getting error as :
Destination Host unreachable.